# How to get 'Code Metrics' out of VS2003?

Tags: visual-studio-2003, code-metrics

I want to use VS2010 power tool 'Code Metrics' with VS2003 Projects and Solutions? do you know how I can manage to do that?

- http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/visual-studio-code-metrics-for-vs2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe using code metrics from the command line:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2011/01/28/code-metrics-from-the-command-line.aspx

and referencing the assemblys.